# Combining keypress and click

Tags: javascript, events, addition

There are posts where this is mentioned but in J Query which i have not learned yet. I have been trying to add the item once the user click on screen or keyboard. When the user clicks on screen it seems to be working perfectly but then when the user presses enter on keyboard, the items shows up for less than a millisecond then disappears. Also, if you can kindly mention how can I add a remove function to remove an item the user click on.
Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Shopping Cart</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <p class="buy">Buy your items anywhere and anytime</p>
    <p class="click">click on an item to remove it</p>
    <form>
        <input type="text" class="item" placeholder="Item:">
        <button type="button">Add item</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <ul>

    </ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the JavaScript:

```
const input = document.querySelector(".item");
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");

function inputLength() {
    return input.value.length;
}
function add() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
function addItem() {
    if (inputLength() > 0) {
        add();
    }
}
function addItemPress(event) {
    if (inputLength() > 0 && event.which === 13) {
        add();
    }
}
btn.addEventListener("click", addItem);
input.addEventListener("keypress", addItemPress)
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, forms will reset the page when they are submitted, unless you set the action property to "#". To run JavaScript when a form is submitted, you can use the onSubmit property. These approaches can be combined like this:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Shopping Cart</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <p class="buy">Buy your items anywhere and anytime</p>
    <p class="click">click on an item to remove it</p>
    <form id="addItemForm" action="#" onsubmit="add()">
        <input type="text" class="item" placeholder="Item:">
        <button type="submit">Add item</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <ul>

    </ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
const input = document.querySelector(".item");
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
const form = document.getElementById("addItemForm");

function add() {
    if (input.value.length > 0) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
        ul.appendChild(li);
        form.reset();
    }
}
```